# See the Javascript microtask queue

Tags: javascript, dom-events, event-loop

Is there any way I can see the microtask queue? or test if the microtask is blocking the macrotask queue?

This is a real issue not being able to see the queuej.

Comment: Have you tried  `Performance` tab in Google Chrome? It provides a lot of information (event log, call tree, etc).

Comment: It is not there